# how to prevent calling method after it has been called when dealing with javascript method chaining?

Tags: javascript, chaining

In this example I would like to call the defineX function before calling the add and value methods

```
class cl {
  #x;
  defineX(n) {
    this.#x = n;
    return this;
  }
  add(n) {
    this.#x += n;
    return this;
  }
  value() {
    return this.#x;
  }
}
const cObj = new cl();

console.log(cObj.defineX(3).add(5).value()); // output 8
console.log(cObj.add(3)) // should not happen
```

what is the best solution so I can prevent calling add before defineX method ??
also how to prevent calling the add method after it has been called for the first time ??

Comment: Store some state in your object and check it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a single `class`, use multiple ones with different methods, each holding a different immutable state. It's simpler without `class` syntax at all though:

```
const cObj = {
  defineX(n) {
    const x = n;
    return {
      add(n) {
        const v = x + n;
        return {
          value() {
            return v;
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
};

console.log(cObj.defineX(3).add(5).value()); // output 8
console.log(cObj.add(3)) // error
```

---

With classes:

```
const cObj = {
  defineX(n) {
    return new Cl(n);
  }
};

class Cl {
  #x;
  constructor(x) {
    this.#x = x;
  }
  add(n) {
    return new Result(this.#x + n);
  }
}

class Result {
  #v;
  constructor(v) {
    this.#v = v;
  }
  value() {
    return this.#v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 1) operations not allowed and 2) breaking from a chain of calls are involved, it seems to me correct  way is to throw an exception whenever something wrong happens. You can always `try/catch` it if you know exception is a possibility.

```js
class cl {
  #x;
  #defined;
  #added;
  defineX(n) {
    this.#x = n;
    this.#defined = true;
    return this;
  }
  add(n) {
    if (!this.#defined) {
      throw new Error("`add` before define")
    }
    if (this.#added) {
      throw new Error("already did `add`")
    }    
    this.#x += n;
    this.#added = true;
    return this;
  }
  value() {
    return this.#x;
  }
}

const cObj = new cl();

// tests:
// console.log(cObj.defineX(3).add(5).value()); // output 8
// console.log(cObj.add(3)) // should not happen - output error
console.log(cObj.defineX(3).add(5).add(6).value()); // output error
```